# how to draw flowchart using retrieve data from sqlserver in asp.net

Tags: c#

I am retrieving data from database and based on that i want to generate a flowchart(in asp.net).  Is there any sample code to solve my problem.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: what do you mean by 'flowchart'

Comment: What you ask isn't trivial. There are a lot of diagramming controls and libraries, that allow you to create a flowchart in code

Comment: Welcome to [so], please read [ask] and search before asking duplicate questions. Thanks and good luck

Comment: i am trying to generate flowchart (in asp.net) in visual studio based on retrieved data not using any tool.how to do this ?